# Shell command for outputting absolute path of binary

Tags: command-line

Is there a shell command for outputing absolute path for specified program?
I'd like to know where executable binary file is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `which ls` to discover full path to `ls` command

Comment: [Don’t use `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/41777), please.

Answer (score 10):

The command

```
type name
```

will give you every information about `name`, if executable (returning also the path), shell alias, shell function, shell builtin.

Comment: And `type -P` to search specifically for binaries

Answer (score 5):

`whereis -b yourBinary` will output the location of a program.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above, with some caveats:

whereis -- searches for matches (by default) on some pre-set directories. The list is available on 'man whereis', and can be passed as a parameter

which -- searches for executable files in the current environment (in other words, executables that can be found in the directories listed in the environment variable PATH

(bash) type -- if 'name' is an alias, it lists the alias definition, but not necessarily the path of any executables in the definition.

Another option, more generic, is [mlocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/mlocate.1.html).

Comment: `type -P` always performs a `PATH` search, `mlocate` would return many unrelated results (unrelated to what OP asked: "absolute path for specified program")

Comment: `type` isn't bash; it's POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/type.html. It should be available on all POSIX-compliant shells.